# Get image pixels of prescribed color

Tags: windows, images, colors, processing, pixels

I have an image (PNG or JPG) inside which there is at least one pixel of a certain RGB color I know in advance.  I want to find the pixel(s) of that color

For example, I may have *image.jpg*, inside which I know some pixel has the RGB value 255,100,200. I want a program that will give me the list of pixels (if any) of that color in the image.

Anyone know of a tool to help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: If your image is a JPG, then you can never be sure that there are a pixel of a certain colour, because JPEG is a lossy compression. With a PNG file, theoretically, you can do it.

Comment: Good point! I'll work with PNG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).  You can then create a list of every pixel in an image using something like:

```
convert foo.jpg foo.txt
```

The text file will contain every pixel in your image, 1 pixel per line:

```
0,0: (230,232,229)  #E6E8E5  rgb(230,232,229)
1,0: (230,232,229)  #E6E8E5  rgb(230,232,229)
2,0: (230,232,229)  #E6E8E5  rgb(230,232,229)
etc
```

If you want to find a single color, try:

```
FINDSTR E6E8E5 foo.txt > lightgrey.txt
```

to dump a file of every pixel containing the color `E6E8E5`.  You can search for the rgb part of the line too, if you'd rather.